# Solr Index slow after a while

Tags: lucene, solr

I use SolrJ to send data to my Solr server.
When I start my program off, it indexes stuff at the rate of about 1000 docs per sec(I commit every 250,000 docs)

I have noticed that when my index is filled up with about 5 million docs, it starts crawling, not just at commit time, add time too.

My Solr server and indexing program run on the same machine

Here are some of the relevant portions from my solrconfig:

> ```
> <useCompoundFile>false</useCompoundFile>
> <ramBufferSizeMB>1024</ramBufferSizeMB>
> <mergeFactor>150</mergeFactor>
> ```

Any suggestions about how to fix this?

Comment: Do you have any idea whats taking so long? Have you tried profiling the index run?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I ended up profiling and found out that solr itself wasn't slow. Bu my client program that was generating content(running in the same machine) was CPU intensive and hence caused the slowness.

Answer (score 1):

that merge factor seems really, really (really) high.

Do you really want that?

If you aren't using compound files that could easily lead to a ulimit problem (if you are linux).